# import cell of matrices and expose true size

Tags: python, scipy

In MATLAB I created a cell array of matrices. There are 30 martices, each of size `20,3`. I loaded it into python and get:

```
import scipy as sp
matlabData = sp.io.loadmat('out.mat')
a = matlabData['myCell']
a.shape
(1,30)
a[0,0].shape
(20,3)
```

I am wondering why the size is initially 'hidden'? How can I make it so that the size of the contents of `a` are immediately apparent?

EDIT: clarifying some questions in comments

```
type(a)
numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: What is the type of a? My guess is that it is an array or a matrix of dtype object.

Comment: I don't see the problem.  It looks like `a` corresponds to the cell array, so its shape matches the shape of the matlab cell array.  `a[0,0]` is the first matrix in the cell array, so it has shape `(20,3)`.

Comment: I agree but since its imported as an `ndarray`, not any type of cell/list/dynamic structure, its unclear why the sizes are burried down. `a` is an `ndarray` not a `list`. It seems more natural to expect to see an `ndarray` that is of size `20,3,30` or similar

Comment: As @Davidmh suggested, check the dtype of `a`.  You'll see that it is an `object` array.  Such an array is a container of arbitrary python objects.  In general, a cell array will not contain arrays that are all the same size, so (in general) creating a 3-D array is not possible.  The current behavior seems like a reasonable way to map the matlab data to numpy data structures.

Comment: I just noticed the edit of the question. To check the `dtype`, take a look at `a.dtype`.